# How to combine different sheet of excel data into a single sheet but different columns?

Tags: excel, pandas, for-loop, excel-formula, concatenation

I have 125 sheets in single excel file (sheet name= 1, 2, .....125). Have to combine all the sheets to master sheet but with different columns. So, the master file will come with 125 columns. I have written the code but it is giving an error.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import os, collections, csv
from os.path  import basename
df = r'C:\Users\Videos\excel\remain.xlsx'
numberOfSheets = 125 #Modify this.
for i in range(1,numberOfSheets+1):    
    data = pd.read_excel(df, sheet_name = str(i), header=None) 
    df.append(data)

final = r'C:\Users\Videos\excel\mergedfile3.xlsx'
df = pd.concat(df)
df.to_excel(final)
```

Please help me to resolve this. Thank you!

Comment: whats the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appending like this will result in a single column, that's probably where your error comes from. Difficult to say without seeing the error.

I would go like this:

Declare a list of series rather than a dataframe

```
list_sheets = []
```

Using your code

```
numberOfSheets = 125 #Modify this.
for i in range(1,numberOfSheets+1):    
    data = pd.read_excel(df, sheet_name = str(i), header=None) 
    list_sheets.append(data)
```

then concat using columns and not rows

```
out_df= pd.concat(list_sheets,axis = 1)
```